# Search a database from an iOS application and display this information

Tags: php, ios

I need to search a database from an iOS application and display this information. I have tried this code:

```
NSString *myRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"type=%@",  type];
NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/search.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
//NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);

NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

This my php code:

```
 <?php

//Your database host server
$db = "ELE";

$type= $_POST["type"];  
 //echo $type;
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost:8888","root","root");
if(!$connect)
{
    die("Database server connection failed.");  
}
else
{
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connect);
    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if(!$dbconnect)
    {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    }
    else
    {
        ////echo "type";
        $query = "select *from ele where type='$type'";
        //echo $query;
        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connect);
        $records = array();
        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset))
        {
            $records[] = $r;    
        }
        //Output the data as JSON
        echo json_encode($records, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
}
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

The string entered will be used in the query, but this isn't working.

I want to return the query result in JSON. The variable type print in debug ny NSLog. When I receive it in php by Post and echo, it is empty.

I expected the query to return JSON and be displayed by the php localhost page.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: So what specific problem are you having?  You are just generally saying you code doesn't work.. how doesn't it work? Where is it failing?  What is it doing that you are not expecting it to do?  What debugging efforts have you made?

Comment: i expect to return jason data, the variable type in my application i debug it by NSLog and its right the problem when i receive it in php by Post then echo it i found no thing displayed in php page on local host and i expect i made the query right and the jason code should be displayed on localhost php page but no thing happen , i am not sure the value of variable type is sent to php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use mysqli if you cannot then dont mix them. see your last line you have `mysqli_close($connect);`

Your code would look like this:

```
<?php
$json = array();

if(isset($_POST['type']){

    $type= $_POST["type"]; 
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM ele WHERE type=?")) {
        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $type);
        /* execute query */
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $records = array();
            /* fetch associative array */
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
                $records[] = $row; 
            }
            /* close connection */
            $mysqli->close();
            $json['success'] = true;
            $json['records'] = $records 
        }else{
            $json['success'] = false;
            $json['message'] = 'failed to SELECT';        
        }

    }

}else{
    $json['success'] = false;
    $json['message'] = 'type is not set';

}
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

As for the parsing the JSON data, you just need to serialize it, so that you can access them, make sure you log everything.

EDIT:

If Your code has still issue, you can try this:

```
-(NSData *)post:(NSString *)postString url:(NSString*)urlString{

    //Response data object
    NSData *returnData = [[NSData alloc]init];

    //Build the Request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Send the Request
    returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];

    //Get the Result of Request
    NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    bool debug = YES;

    if (debug && response) {
        NSLog(@"Response >>>> %@",response);
    }


    return returnData;
}
```

Usage:

```
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"type=%@",type];
NSString *urlString = @"https://www.yourapi.com";

NSData *returnData =  [self post:postString url:urlString];

NSDictionary *jsonData = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
if (returnData !=nil) {
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", returnData); 
    jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData 
                                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                                 error:nil];
    bool success = [jsonData[@"success"] boolValue];
    if(success){
       NSArray *records = jsonData[@"records"];
       NSLog(@"records = %@", records);
    }else{
        NSString *error = jsonData[@"message"];
        NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
    }
}else{
    NSLog(@"responseData is nil"); 
}
```

Comment: i discovered that $type=$_post["type"]; the value in this variable is null as no thing get sent to it. so i think my problem in sending data to the server so in my ios code is there are something wrong in sending data?????

Comment: @user3045517 have you try to log it?,have you ever used this function to perform a request?

Comment: yes if you have another i can try it, but notice variable type in ios depend on when i click on uicollectionview cell i get cell information and go to another viewcontroller so variable type is depend on which cell i choosed using function prepareforsegue